# Making a query of a query

Tags: sql, visual-studio, datagridview, dataset

In Visual studio I show the results of this datasetquery :

```
SELECT *,uv,hours,minutes FROM dbo.kbpres
 INNER JOIN
doss ON kbpres.ino = doss.ino
 where doss.dosnm LIKE @cboDossiernm
```

But now I want to show in another datagridview  the sum of all hours and minutes of the uv (which are names of the persons who worked on a certain case) So for instance in the original DGview I have

```
     - blablabla  /  person1  /  1  /  0
     - blablabla  /  person2  /  5  /  0
     - blablabla  /  person3  /  1  /  0
     - blablabla  /  person1  /  1  /  0
     - blablabla  /  person1  /  1  /  0
     - blablabla  /  person4  /  1  /  0
```

And in my second DGview I want to see :

```
     - person 1 /  3  / 0 
     - person 2 /  5  / 0 
     - person 3 /  1  / 0 ....
```

How do I do this best ?

Comment: Have a look at LINQ, since you have all the data you need returned from your database already you should be able to run a linq query against it to get the results you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583463/join-multiple-datarows-into-a-single-datarow) that deals with manipulating the results of a query in memory. There is also some advice offered that you should perform your aggregation at the DB level.

HTH

Comment: I read it but I don't understand it quite :

var aggregatedAddresses = from DataRow row in dt.Rows 
group row by row["AddressA"] into g 
select new { 
    Address = g.Key, 
    Byte = g.Sum(row => (uint)row["Bytes"]) 
}; 
 
int i = 1; 
foreach(var row in aggregatedAddresses) 
{ 
    result.Rows.Add(i++, row.Address, row.Byte); 
} 

With me  Byte = g.Sum(row => (uint)row["Bytes"])    "Bytes", is a column called hours which is just a number like 4 or 2. When I would use my colun it doesnt work. How should I use it for me ??

Comment: Exact code I used is :
 DataTable table;
table = togaDataSet.Tables["kbpres"];
var query = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
 group row by row.Field<string>("uv") into grp
 orderby grp.Key
 select new
 {
 Id = grp.Key,
 Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("uur")),
 Minuut = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("minuut")),
 };
int i = 1; 
foreach (var grp in query)
 {
 //Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", grp.Id, grp.Sum);
 dataGridView2.Rows.Add(i++, grp.Id, grp.Sum,grp.Minuut); 
  
 }
 dataGridView2.Rows.Add("","Totale som",table.Compute("Sum(uur)", "uur > 0"),table.Compute("Sum(Minuut)", "minuut > 0"));